# Curl upload a file using ansible shell module, how to verify the status code

Tags: regex, ansible, http-response-codes

I am trying to upload a file by using curl in ansible. URI module does not support file upload, so I tried using curl directly via shell module as follows:

```
- name: Upload config
    shell: 'curl -w "%{http_code}\\n" --insecure -X PUT -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
            -H "Authorization: Token $$$$" \
            https://abc.xyz.com/api/upload_file/ \
            -F "file=@var/config.txt" -s -o /dev/null'
    register: result

  - name: Set http response code for uploading config
    set_fact:
      config_upload_status: "{{ result.stdout }}"
```

I am not sure the best way to verify the http status here as the shell command always returns true, even if file upload is failed, so tried to capture the http return code, but from here what to try to ascertain if upload is passed say 2[0-9][0-9] or failed?

Comment: are you aware of the `--fail` flag to `curl`, which will cause it to return a non-zero exit code on HTTP errors?

Comment: Thanks @mdaniel I guess this did the trick-

Comment: `- name: upload config file
    shell: 'curl -s --fail --show-error --insecure -X PUT -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
            -H "Authorization: Token {{ api_token }}" \
            https://abc.xyz.com/api/file_upload \
            -F "ssh_key_file=@var/tmp/config.txt" -F "username=test"'
    register: result
    failed_when: result.rc != 0`